# Numeric vector of 0s, into a matrix 360x720

Tags: r, vector

I want to create a numeric vector of 0s, which i can then put into a matrix of 360 rows x 720 columns (1x1 grid of the world)

Could anyone give me any advice on how to do this?

Comment: `numeric(360*720)`

Answer (score 0):

no need for the vector. R recycles short vectors. Hence a vector with one element is sufficient in this case.

```
matrix(0, nrow = 360, ncol = 720)
```